# Losing underscores in fields name when inserting in mongo with mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

I have the something like the following code:

```
import (
  ...
  "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
  "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type User struct {
  Id bson.ObjectId      `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
  MessengerUserId int64 `bson: "messenger_user_id"`
  ...
}
...
newUser = User{...}
usersCollection.Insert(&newUser)
```

And in mongo shell i'm making:

```
db.users.find()
```

and getting

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("XXXXXXXXXXXXX"), "messengeruserid" : NumberLong(123456789) ... }
```

Why `messenger_user_id` field loses underscores in it? I'm using `MongoDB server version: 3.4.4` and `mgo.v2`

Comment: You must not insert a space in the tag between the key and value: `bson:"messenger_user_id"`.

Comment: You have a space after the colon in `bson: "messenger_user_id"` which I think is invalid.

Comment: Yes, you are right guys